# Run terminal application from bat file, timeout the bat file then give commands to the application

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, drone.io

I'm struggeling with a problem here. I want to run a bat file which writes a mission to my drone using MAVProxy.

I can start MAVProxy from my bat file but there is something I dont get.
When I execute this command: `mavproxy.exe --master=com6 --baudrate=57600`
MAVProxy starts within the console. Next I want to wait a minute to make sure MAVProxy has a connection with the drone.

In my bat file I used timeout:  `timeout /t 60`. After the minute has passed I want to give a command to MAVProxy which runs in the cmd window. The command I want to give is the following: `wp load route.waypoints`.
However this does not work, the bat file just does not do anything until I CTRL+C in the cmd window.

Does anyone have a clue how to give these commands with a bat file?

My complete bat file:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\MAVProxy
mavproxy.exe --master=com6 --baudrate=57600
timeout /t 60
wp load route.waypoints
```

I hope someone know a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Change `mavproxy.exe --master=com6 --baudrate=57600` to `start mavproxy.exe --master=com6 --baudrate=57600`

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand right? `wp load route.waypoints` is an input that is requested by `mavproxy.exe`?

Completely depends on how `mavproxy.exe` is programmed.

the following could (or could not) work:

```
(timeout /t 60>nul &echo wp load route.waypoints)|mavproxy.exe --master=com6 --baudrate=57600
```

If this doesn't work, there is no pure batch solution, but some embedded vba code is able to `sendkey` to an application.